# Message Collector not worth

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a support command: you type a command, the bot send you a message and then you reply to that message. I've used the awaitMessages function but it doesn't work.

```
case `support` : {
      message.channel.send("What's your problem?");
      let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
      let msg = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {maxMatches: 1});
      message.channel.send("Your problem is: " + msg.first().content);

      break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `.then()` you need to return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). This is a basic example of how you can use Promise:

```
const myFunction = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(taskIsSuccesFullyDone)
        {
            resolve(true); // Pass anything
        }else{

            reject('Something went wrong!');
        }
    });
}


myFunction().then(() => {
    // Task is succesful completed.
    // Do anything
})
.catch(error => console.log(error.message || error));
```

In your case, your code would look something like this:

```
function support_message() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        message.author.send(`Hello, <@${message.author.id}>, reply to this message explaining the problem you have.`)
        .then(message => resolve(message))
        .catch((error) => {
            message.reply("I can't send you messages, be sure that you allow direct messages from unknown users to use this command.");
            reject(error);
        })
    });
}

case `staff-support` : {
    support_message().then(message => {
        // We got the message object passed from the resolved Promise
        // Do anything here
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        // There was a problem!
        // Do anything here.
    });
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have other problem with the Message Collector right now tho. So I've edited the post

Comment: @manujonex It's a bit unclear what kind of problem you have with the message collector. Can you please explain or edit your post to make it understandable?